# Отображение символов Unicode в виджете tkinter Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, unicode

При написании программы с использованием tkinter возникла проблема: Вводя сивмолы Unicode в виджет Entry, вместо самих символов отображаются знаки вопроса․ Помогите пожалуйста исправить это. Заранее спасибо.

```
root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
entry_play = Entry(root, textvariable=v)
entry_play.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: какого вида символы?

Comment: Армянский алфавит, находиться в диапазоне (1377, 1417)

Comment: Странно попробовал как вы сказали, [но  у меня никаких проблем не возникло](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBjUa.png)

Comment: У меня они отображаются в остальных виджетах, но в Entry нет․ То есть когда я ввожу символы,  в Entry появляются ՛?, а допустим в Label все работает.

Comment: @Андрей так только в окнах Tk? В блокноте например вы можете эти символы нормально ввести?